# RenderPartial will not fire controller ActionResult Method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Razor view containing a partial view that I want to update when the user clicks the refresh button on my pop up

The code executes with no errors, but my breakpoint in the controller method PricingUpdate does not fire. If I add alerts to my JavaScript this tells me the Javascript is firing OK

I can't see anything wrong with what I have, I am suspicious of the url variable string value, i.e. `var url = 'Supplypoint/PricingUpdate';` but i've tried many variations

My Controller Method :

```
public ActionResult PricingUpdate(DateTime StartDate,DateTime EndDate, int SupplyPointId)
{

    var obj = _db.GetSupplyPoint(SupplyPointId);

    _db.SupplyPointCalculateWastePricing(obj, StartDate, EndDate);
    _db.SupplyPointCalculatePricing(obj, StartDate, EndDate);

    var supplyPoint = _db.GetSupplyPoint(SupplyPointId);
    return PartialView("_DetailsPricing", supplyPoint);
}
```

My main View code extract :

```
            <div id="ResultsList" style="clear:both;">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("_DetailsPricing", Model);}
            </div>
```

My script code in the main View :

```
    $("#RefreshBtn").click(function () {
        var url = 'Supplypoint/PricingUpdate';

        var data = {  
            StartDate: $('#StartDate').val(),
            EndDate: $('#EndDate').val(),
            SupplyPointId: $('#SupplyPointId').val().toString()
        };

        $("#ResultsList").load(url,data,function () {
            $('#LoadingGif').empty(); 

        });

        $('#LoadingGif').empty().html('<img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" width=31 height=31 alt="Loading image" />'); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yikes I had called my date inputs by the wrong name, changed code to : (all ok now)

```
            var data = {  
                StartDate: $('#from').val(),
                EndDate: $('#to').val(),
                SupplyPointId: $('#SupplyPointId').val().toString()
            };
```